# Simple question about the Google Sitemap

Tags: sitemap

Can I code my sitemap this way and expect Google to crawl every links contain in the following page I have inserted below? Thanks!

```
<url> 
 <loc>http://www.domain.com/page/1</loc> 
 <lastmod>2010-11-28</lastmod> 
 <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
 <priority>0.2</priority> 
</url>
<url> 
 <loc>http://www.domain.com/page/2</loc> 
 <lastmod>2010-11-28</lastmod> 
 <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
 <priority>0.2</priority> 
</url>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes

but don'T bother to much with changefreq or priority, it does not really do anything (according to my tests)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I'm going to try it out myself. :)